# Load to ship assignment problem

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, combinatorial-optimization, assignment-problem

**Problem**

We’d like to optimize the delivery of loads across a network using a fleet of ships. Assume there is a set of $\mathcal{S}$ ships that need to deliver the set of $\mathcal{L}$ loads in a single day. Let the profit of moving load $j ∈ \mathcal{L}$ with ship $i \in \mathcal{S}$ be given by $w_{ij}$.

- The ship can also chose to not move a load at all (and stay put) at $0$ profit.
- Assume we can only assign a ship to one load per day
- A load may be taken by at most one ship
- Not all loads necessarily need to be moved.

I need to make a model for optimizing profit by formulating the assignment problem for a single day as an integer program and a continuous LP version of it.

**Here is my take:**

We can model this problem as in a weighted bipartite graph, a matching of a given size, in which the sum of weights of the edges is maximum. Each edge $(i, j)$, where $i$ is in $\mathcal{S}$ and $j$ is in $\mathcal{L}$, has a profit $w_{ij}$. For each edge $(i, j)$ we have a variable $x_{ij}$. The variable is $1$ if the edge is contained in the matching and $0$ otherwise, so we set the domain constraints:

$$
x_{ij} = \{0, 1\} \quad \text{for} \quad i, j \in \mathcal{S},\mathcal{L}
$$

The total weight of the matching is

$$
\sum_{(i,j) \in \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{L}} x_{ij} w_{ij}
$$

The goal is to find a perfect matching that maximizes the above objective function. To guarantee that the variables represent a perfect matching, we add constraints saying that each vertex is adjacent to exactly one edge in the matching, i.e,

$$
\sum_{j \in \mathcal{L}} x_{ij} = 1 \quad \text{for} \quad i \in \mathcal{S}\\
\sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} x_{ij} = 1 \quad \text{for} \quad j \in \mathcal{L}
$$

Therefore, the problem can be formulated as –

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
    \text{maximize} & \sum_{(i,j) \in \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{L}} x_{ij}w_{ij}\\
    \text{subject to} \\
& \sum_{j \in \mathcal{L}} x_{ij} = 1 \quad \text{for} \quad i \in \mathcal{S}\notag \\
    & \sum_{i \in \mathcal{S}} x_{ij} = 1 \quad \text{for} \quad j \in \mathcal{L}\notag \\
    \text{where,} \qquad & x_{ij} = \{0,1\} \quad \text{for} \quad i,j \in \mathcal{S},\mathcal{L} \notag
\end{eqnarray}
$$

**LP version:**

We can solve it without the integrality constraints, using standard methods for solving continuous linear programs. We can just use this constraint instead –

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
    0 \leq x_{ij} \leq 1 \quad \text{for} \quad i,j \in \mathcal{S},\mathcal{L}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Am I doing it right?

Comment: In a perfect matching, every load goes on exactly one ship and every ship carries exactly one load. Compare that to your problem statement.

Comment: @pubin I see, is it an "unbalanced" version of the assignment problem? In that case how should I formulate it? Because the number of vertices on the either side of the bipartite graph will not be the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can treat this as a [generalized assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem), assigning loads to ships, with real ships having capacity one load each and with a dummy "ship" with capacity $\vert \mathcal{L} \vert$ representing loads that are not moved.

Comment: I think it should be something like $|\mathcal{L} - \mathcal{S}|$ extra imaginary "ships" if $\mathcal{S} < \mathcal{L}$ (and vise-versa), right? But how do I express this idea in a mathematical formula?

Comment: I was assuming an inequality constraint for the load allocated to the dummy "ship" and did not give the minimum workable capacity. The dummy "ship" needs a capacity of at least $max\lbrace 0, \vert \mathcal{L}\vert - \vert \mathcal{S}\vert\rbrace.$ If some loads have negative weights (you did not specify the sign of $w$), then you may need a larger capacity (to avoid forcing ships to take negative weight loads). Setting the capacity to $\vert \mathcal{L} \vert$ is a safe choice (assuming an inequality constraint on its load).